# Memory block alternative that ISN'T fixed in minor time step?

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, s-function

I have a model with some inputs that are fed into a CMEX S-Function via the Memory block, and the S-Function provides outputs based on these inputs, and those inputs are fed back into the S-Function. Classic algebraic loop scenario. I was using a memory block to prevent this because our solver is usually variable-time step

According to the [Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/memory.html) the Memory Block, and the Unit Delay block also, are fixed in minor time step in terms of their outputs. I realize that the *inputs* can be either discrete or continuous, but the *output* will only be continuous in the *major* time step, and fixed in the minor one.

Now, for various reasons, it is important to us that everything in the model get updated in the minor *and* major time steps. I came up with a way of using the PWork vector to store the previous value of state points and forward them to the CMEX S-Function that we use. This prevents algebraic loops from occuring and also ensures continuous in minor time step, but is not as elegant as I would like.

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions?

*PS: As an aside, I believe that it is better to use the Memory block regardless of if my solver is Fixed Step or Variable Step, because it will internally just become a Unit Delay block for Fixed Step solvers. Is this assumption correct?*

Comment: NOTE: Since asking this question, I have spoken to engineers at Mathworks, who have informed me that it is not possible to have an alternative that isn't fixed in the minor time step. We tried a range of options: using mdlUpdate to update values (however, it gets called only in the major steps), creating our own s-function that imitates the memory block, but in the minor time step (simulink does not give access to us to update the imitation-block's states in the minor steps). In the end, it was concluded that we have to live with this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2015/07/18/why-you-should-never-break-an-algebraic-loop-with-with-a-memory-block/), using fast-response transfer function may achieve similar result without going into minor step.